# How to limit variables of dotplot?

Tags: r, plot

I want to create a dotplot which comprises only the top 10 values of the features in the text file. The following code works, but the output is a dotplot containing all 160 variables.

```
library(lattice)
table<-"imp_s2.txt"
DT<-read.table(table, header=T)
# output graph to pdf file 
pdf("dotplot_s2.pdf")
colnames(DT)

DT$feature <- reorder(DT$feature, DT$IncMSE)

dotplot(feature ~ IncMSE, data = DT,
        aspect = 1.5,
        xlab = "Variable Importance, Scale 2",
        scales = list(cex = .6),
        panel = function (x, y) {
          panel.abline(h = as.numeric(y), col = "gray", lty = 2)
          panel.xyplot(x, as.numeric(y), col = "black", pch = 16)})
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you included a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  My guess is that this can be done by simply subsetting your data frame so that you are including only the rows with the top 10 values.  Something like this might work (although I can't test it):

```
# get threshold value
cutoff <- sort(DT$IncMSE, decreasing=TRUE)[10]

dotplot(feature ~ IncMSE, 
        data = DT[which(DT$IncMSE>=cutoff),], # this only includes top values
        aspect = 1.5,
        xlab = "Variable Importance, Scale 2",
        scales = list(cex = .6),
        panel = function (x, y) {
          panel.abline(h = as.numeric(y), col = "gray", lty = 2)
          panel.xyplot(x, as.numeric(y), col = "black", pch = 16)})
```